# Python Method TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask project (Python 3.6) Im playing with and running into issues with pulling data in via an API GET and adding additional values to the data before passing it to the front end.

Ive created a separate module to do this work with the following in the class PortfolioPerf and am stuck getting it working.

```
class PortfolioPerf(object):

def stock_quantity(self, portfolio, stock):

    # Load portfolio
    portload = self.portfolio_read(portfolio)

    # Total of each crypto owned
    holdings = {name: 0 for name in stock}
    for s in portload:
        holdings[s['symbol']] += s['amount']

    return holdings

def portfolio_add_perf(self, portfolio, stock, stock_url):

    # Add total amount owned to my_data
    total_stock = self.stock_quantity(portfolio, stock)
    for k, v in total_stock.items():
        my_data['RAW'][k]['USD']['AmountOwned'] = v

    return my_data
```

I call the class and portfolio_add_perf method within my flask app here

```
portfolio = './portfolio.json'
stock = ['CSCO', 'IBM', 'NVDA']
stock_url = "https://urltostockdata.blah"

@app.route('/')
def home():

p = PortfolioPerf()
stock_data = p.portfolio_add_perf(portfolio, stock, stock_url)
```

portfolio, stock and stock_url are all defined here as well. When I run this I get the following error.

```
File "/app/PortfolioPerf.py", line 43, in stock_quantity
  holdings = {name: 0 for name in stock}
TfypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I have no idea why the method has an issue with stock. Ive even tried to define a new variable inside the method to use it but that does the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show what values you are using for `portfolio, stock` and, `stock_url`?  Also, can you show the full code for `PortfolioPerf `

Comment: I'm guessing `stock` is a generator function and needs to be called first to produce an iterable object. For example, you could change the offending line to: `holdings = {name: 0 for name in stock()}`. This is just a wild guess, it will not be possible to help you without the context of the remainder of your application.

Comment: @ClockSlave, added the variables in the flask app. So they are hard set in the app which then sends them to the class PortfolioPerf to portfolio_add_perf method. That method them pushes them through another method stock_quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not just a typo. You get this error because `stock` is (most likely) a function which returns some sequence like list or tuple. Change the call to:

```
holdings = {name: 0 for name in stock()}
```

And it should work.